# Looking for name of a book about a mechanic boy and princess who survived a space ship crash and hated each other

Tags: story-identification, books

The book had a title that was sort of similar to "when stars align" or "when two collide" or something. It was about a space ship mechanic boy who was one of the sole survivors of a spaceship crash. The other survivor was a princess and they hated each other but as they continued to survive together, they grew together and understood each other. I really only vaguely remember bits and pieces of it. I know that the princess accidentally exploded herself and there was this weird part about blue light.... I really want to find it again.

Comment: I hope I've done a good enough job of trying to summarise what you're looking for in a pithy title (I'll trust the community to improve upon what I've done if not). Also welcome to Sci Fi stack exchange! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here and visit the [help] for more guidance!

Comment: Can you had more infos ? Do you remember if it was a one shot or a book serie ? When did you read it ? Do you know approximately the year it was released ? And do you remember where the story takes place ?

Comment: A. E. van Vogt's fix-up novel Mission to the Stars (also known as The Mixed Men) had a similar part, as I recall. Maybe it's worth a look.

Comment: @Razor The part you're thinking about was originally published as a novelette titled "The Storm". First thing I thought of when I saw the question, but the details didn't seem to match. "The Storm" is available at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v32n02_1943-10_cape1736/page/n7/mode/2up

Comment: @user14111 Thanks! We only got the novel version in Hungary, and I didn't had it at hand to check.

Comment: @Razor Szivesen!

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Keith Laumer's "[Galactic Odyssey](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1549283.Galactic_Odyssey)".

The 2 people stranded on the planet are a Princess and a young man who is a "gun-bearer" for the rich spaceship owner who is a hunter who travels around to different planets to hunt dangerous animals with his friends.

When the owner and fellow hunters are killed, the Princess and gun-bearer are stuck on the planet because they don't know the pass-codes re-enter the ship.

Various covers are out there, but this is the one I remember.

[image]

CONS: I don't not recall an explosion of blue light that almost kills the Princes. But the hunters weapons do exhibit a blue flash when fired: *"I heard the Z-gun make a sharp whickering noise and an electric-blue light flashed up and lit the rocks like lightning,"*

Comment: A good story, but: no spaceship crash; Billy Danger was not a spaceship mechanic when he was stranded with the Lady Raire, though he became one later; they never hated each other; the Lady didn't explode herself; I don't recall any blue light either, and the title doesn't match. the OP's vague recollections.

Answer (score 2):

This may be *These Broken Stars* by Amie Kaufman and Meagan Spooner, the first Starbound book.

He is a military officer, very high ranking for his age because of some heroics, and she is the daughter of a fantastically rich and powerful man.  (He does have some technical knowledge that she doesn't, which they need to survive, but actually, she's the one with mechanical knowledge.)  They are the sole survivors of a crash landing on a planet where they do grow together after much conflict.

> She is killed when she uses explosives to open up a location.  There are aliens involved and she comes back.  There may or may not have been blue light involved, I do not remember  the details.